# Delphi TXMLNodeCollection.AddItem inserts in the wrong position

Tags: xml, delphi, insert

I'm in Delphi XE2 and using TXMLNodeCollection.AddItem to insert IXMLNode to my list in position 1. I have two nodes in my list already. What it does instead is insert into position 0. When I try to adjust it by inserting into position 2 thinking it will go to 1 it actually inserts into position 2 at the end.

Here is the code:

```
TXMLChartTemplateRowList = class(TXMLNodeCollection, IXMLChartTemplateRowList)
protected
  { IXMLChartTemplateRowList }
  function Add: IXMLChartTemplateRow;
  function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLChartTemplateRow;

  function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLChartTemplateRow;
end;

implementation

function TXMLChartTemplateRowList.Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLChartTemplateRow;
begin
  Result := AddItem(Index) as IXMLChartTemplateRow;
end;
```

I'm stumped please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that calling the Resync method from the TXMLNodeCollection class after modifying the list resolves this issue.